# Solve :$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y^2+x}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y^2+x}$

Given that the curve passes through $(0,1)$.

I tried to reduce this to Clairaut's form but was unable to proceed.

Comment: i think there exists no analytical solution

Comment: What about $y(x) = t(x) \cdot \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: Wolfram has no success so I'm included to agree with there being no nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y^2+x}\quad\text{with condition } y(0)=1$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{y^2}}$$

There is no simple closed form for the solution, but one can find approximates.

Asymptotically, for $x$ increasing $y$ increases faster because $y'(x)>2$. Thus $\frac{x}{y^2}\to 0$.

$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}\simeq 2 \quad\to\quad y\simeq e^{2x}\quad$ This is the first approximate.

More accurate approximates for low values of $x$ can be derived on the form of series expansion, for example on the form :

$$y(x)\simeq  e^{2x} +a_0 + a_1 x+a_2 x^2 +...$$

$a_0=0$ because $y(0)=1$

Bringing the above $y(x)$ into the ODE and expanding it into series leads to $a_1=0$ and $a_2=\frac{1}{2}$

$$y(x)\simeq e^{2x} +\frac{1}{2} x^2 $$

The figure below shows that the approximate is already good :

- The black curve is the representation of the solution of the ODE (from numerical solving of the ODE)
- The blue curve represents the first approximate $y(x)=e^{2x}$
- The red curve represents the second approximate $y(x)= e^{2x} +\frac{1}{2} x^2 $

[image]

An even better approach consists in expanding the square root in power series of $\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\right)$
$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{y^2}}\simeq 2+\frac{x}{y^2}+O\left(\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\right)^2\right)$$

The solution of $\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}= 2+\frac{x}{y^2}$ , with condition $y(0)=1$ is :
$$y(x)=e^{2x}\sqrt{\frac{9-(4x+1)e^{-4x}}{8}}$$
This function is not drawn on the figure because it is so close to the exact solution that the two curves cannot be distinguished one to the other.

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y^2+x}$ with $y(x=0)=1$

$2\sqrt{y^2+x}~\dfrac{dx}{dy}=1$ with $x(y=1)=0$

Let $u=\sqrt{y^2+x}$ ,

Then $x=u^2-y^2$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=2u\dfrac{du}{dy}-2y$

$\therefore2u\left(2u\dfrac{du}{dy}-2y\right)=1$ with $u(y=1)=1$

$4u^2\dfrac{du}{dy}-4uy=1$ with $u(y=1)=1$

$4u^2\dfrac{du}{dy}=4uy+1$ with $u(y=1)=1$

$\left(y+\dfrac{1}{4u}\right)\dfrac{dy}{du}=u$ with $y(u=1)=1$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $v=y+\dfrac{1}{4u}$ ,

Then $y=v-\dfrac{1}{4u}$

$\dfrac{dy}{du}=\dfrac{dv}{du}+\dfrac{1}{4u^2}$

$\therefore v\left(\dfrac{dv}{du}+\dfrac{1}{4u^2}\right)=u$ with $v(u=1)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{du}+\dfrac{v}{4u^2}=u$ with $v(u=1)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{du}=-\dfrac{v}{4u^2}+u$ with $v(u=1)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

Let $t=\dfrac{1}{4u}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{du}=-\dfrac{1}{4u^2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{v}{4u^2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}=-\dfrac{v}{4u^2}+u$ with $v\left(t=\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v-4u^3$ with $v\left(t=\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}-v=-\dfrac{1}{16t^3}$ with $v\left(t=\dfrac{1}{4}\right)=\dfrac{5}{4}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf